# Cannot select rows out of numpy array to perform an std

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, row

`import numpy as Np`
I need to calculate the std on the first three rows of a numPy array I 
 made with `y = Np.random(100, size = (5, 3))`.

The above produced the array I am working on. Note that I have since calculated the median of the array after having removed the 2 smallest values in the array with:
 `y=Np.delete(y, y.argmin())`
 `y=Np.delete(y, y.argmin())` 
`Np.median(y)`

When I call `y` now it no longer is in a square matrix. It comes all on one line like array([48, 90, 67, 26, 53, 16, 19, 64, 51, 47, 54, 91, 36]).

When I try to slice it and calculate an standard deviation (`std`) I get an IndexError. I think it is because this array is now a tuple.

Comment: What is `Np`? Is it `numpy.random`?

Comment: Please place the code in correct format. It is pretty hard to analyze anything now.

Comment: My apologies for lack of clarity. Do I need to wrap the code in back ticks or something similar? In answer to "what is `Np`" yes it is what you thought. I imported it first but did not include that in my post. I see now that must have been very confusing. Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people suggested the question format is not clear. Here what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.random.randint(100, size = (5, 3))
y 
array([[65, 84, 56],
   [90, 44, 42],
   [51, 58,  9],
   [82,  1, 91],
   [96, 32, 24]])
```

Now to compute `std` for each row:

```
y.std(axis=1)
array([11.6714276 , 22.1710522 , 21.63844316, 40.47221269, 32.22145593])
```

Since you just want the first 3 rows you can slice the result:

```
result = y.std(axis=1)[:3]
result
array([11.6714276 , 22.1710522 , 21.63844316])
```

Alternatively you can first select/slice the 1st 3 rows and then use `std`:

```
y[:3].std(axis=1)
array([11.6714276 , 22.1710522 , 21.63844316])
```

Comment: This solution produces an IndexError. Both solutions you have kindly provided produce the same IndexError when I use them in colab. The error reports tuple index out of range, then points to ---> 57         items *= arr.shape[ax]. I tried coverting it to `Np.asarray(y)` to no avail. Do I need to turn `y` into a square matrix?

Comment: If you try my code all together top to bottom, it doesn't raise any error. I think you should provide better code in the question. For example Np cannot be numpy.random nor numpy, if it were, then Np.random(100, size = (5, 3)) would already raise an error.

Comment: Once I originally produced the array, I have performed maths upon it. Not only simple divsion and multiplication, I also removed the 2 smallest values then calculated the median. So now my array is different than it once was so it is a tuple now? I am shooting in the dark here why its not working for me.

Comment: Again, you may want to add more of your code, or use operations on a copy of the array, or calculate and store std before anything else and use it later for whatever your goal is. There are many solutions I guess :)